# SQL Server get non-matching values from two tables

Tags: sql-server

Here's the scenario: In a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, Table A has StudyID, VisitCode and VisitSequenceNumber. Table B has StudyID, SubjectID and VisitCode.

Table A has all possible VisitCodes for a given StudyID (There are over 200 StudyIDs in this table, each with its own set of VisitCodes).

Table B has all SubjectIDs for a given StudyID, as well as all VisitIDs for each subject (There are over 200 StudyIDs in this table, each with its own set of SubjectIDs).

I need to create a list of all SubjectIDs for a StudyID, aling with all the VisitIDs that the SubjectID does NOT have.  I can't just make a list of SubjectIDs with missing visits, I need to identify which visits are missing for each subject.

So if for StudyID 'C1234' Table A has this:

```
StudyID | VisitCode | VisitSequenceNumber
C1234   | V100A     | 100
C1234   | V110A     | 110
C1234   | V120A     | 120
C1234   | UNS       | 999
```

And Table B has:

```
StudyID |SubjectID | VisitCode
C1234   | 01-001   | V100A
C1234   | 01-001   | V120A
C1234   | 01-001   | UNS
C1234   | 01-002   | V110A
C1234   | 01-002   | UNS
```

I need to return rows that would contain the following:

```
StudyID | SubjectID | VisitCode
C1234   | 01-001    | V110A
C1234   | 01-002    | V100A
C1234   | 01-002    | V120A
```

For some reason I just can't seem to work this one out - how do I match up the Subjects with the missing Visits when they are by definition not in Table B for those Subjects?  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You question is not entirely clear (what you want to return: A better example or description will help). For now: Use a LEFT JOIN:
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.studyID=b.studyID + a WHERE filter to drop any data you do not want.

Comment: According to me, you should have included the table details for subject also.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen - I need a list that matches each SubjectID with the VisitIDs that are NOT in Table B for that SubjectID.

Comment: @JeffK627 Can you correct your output?  If I understand the requirement, V110A should not be in there because it is in both tables.

Comment: The output is correct. Subject 01-001 never had Visit V110A, so the output should be as shown for that Subject. Subject 01-002 did not have Visits V100A or V120A, so those visits should be matched with that Subject in the output.

Comment: Table A is to show all possible Visits for the Study. Table B is to show which visits each Subject has had. Output is to show which Visits each Subject is missing.

Comment: That clears it up, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce some kind of master list for the required `subjectID`s and `visitCodes`.

**Edit**

I get all possible values for `studyID` from tableB (here: limited to 'C1234'), all values for `subjectID` from tableB again and all values for `visitCodes` from tableA. After that I run a join between all these possible values and check whether the combination already exists in tableB

```
SELECT sti studyId, sid studyId, vc visitCode
FROM 
 ( SELECT DISTINCT studyID sti FROM tableB ) stis
 INNER JOIN 
 ( SELECT DISTINCT StudyID ssi,subjectID sid FROM tableB) s ON ssi=sti
 INNER JOIN 
 ( SELECT DISTINCT StudyID vsi,visitCode vc FROM tableA ) v ON vsi=sti
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB  
      WHERE StudyID=sti AND subjectID=sid AND visitCode=vc)
AND sti = 'C1234' -- to limit the example to the current study
```

See here for a working demo (MySQL): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc91b/11
or here (T-SQL 2014): [demo on data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/334523/demo-for-31324399)

Comment: OK, the code was a bit buggy at first, but it works now - please check my fiddle again!

Comment: This is looking like it might work once I tweak it for the actual environment - I'll let you know!

Comment: I have to test further, but for the test studies I have this works. I'm marking it as the answer. Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `cross join` in a derived table to generate all possible combinations of StudyID, VisitCode and SubjectId and then left join with that set and filter for null to find the missing rows:

```
select all_combo.studyid, all_combo.subjectid, all_combo.visitcode
from (
    select a.studyid, a.visitcode, b.subjectid 
    from tableb b 
    cross join tablea a 
    group by a.studyid, a.visitcode, b.subjectid 
) all_combo
left join tableb b 
 on all_combo.VisitCode = b.VisitCode 
and all_combo.StudyID = b.StudyID 
and all_combo.SubjectID = b.SubjectID 
where b.StudyID is null
  and all_combo.StudyID = 'C1234' -- you might have to limit to the specific StudyID
order by all_combo.SubjectID;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18e4b/1)

Result with your sample data:

```
| studyid | subjectid | visitcode |
|---------|-----------|-----------|
|   C1234 |    01-001 |    V110A  |
|   C1234 |    01-002 |    V100A  |
|   C1234 |    01-002 |    V120A  |
```

Comment: The cross join might not be the best idea. If you have a different visitcode on a different study it will show up http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95d1f/1 I honestly don't know if it's correct or not for the op

Comment: That's true, although it could be handled by adding another condition `all_combo.StudyID = 'C1234'` , but there are most likely better ways of dealing with it (like maybe yours).

Comment: @jpw - I've been trying to test your solution, but in the real environment it takes forever to run.  I should probably make it clear that TableB is very large - it contains values for over 200 Studies and each one may have 50 to 100 Subjects. I think filtering for the specific Study needs to happen in the definition of all_combo, trying that now.

Comment: @JeffK627 Ah yes, given a large set of data the cross join will explode, so limiting it with a clause like `where b.StudyID = 'C1234'` should make it faster, but then of course your limited to one specific study at a time, but maybe that's ok.

Comment: "but then of course your limited to one specific study at a time, but maybe that's ok"

That's actually a requirement - just return results for the Study selected by the User.

Comment: @JeffK627 Oh, I must have missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that makes this difficult is you don't have a table that defindes which subjects are associated with a studyid so we have to derive it from b. Using a CTE will do that. Also the JOIN to tableB is wierd because it uses the distinct set of {StudyId, subjectID} as well as the possible visits

```
WITH subjects 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT studyid, 
                         subjectid 
         FROM   tableb) 
SELECT s.studyid, 
       s.subjectid, 
       a.visitcode 
FROM   subjects s 
       INNER JOIN tablea a 
               ON s.studyid = a.studyid 
       LEFT JOIN tableb b 
              ON a.studyid = b.studyid 
                 AND a.visitcode = b.visitcode 
                 AND s.subjectid = b.subjectid 
WHERE  b.studyid IS NULL 
ORDER  BY s.studyid, 
          s.subjectid
```

[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/334504/demo-for-31324399)

Comment: Table B has the Subject IDs for each StudyID.  There are multiple StudyIDs in that table, I need to pull the output for whatever StudyID the user selects.

Comment: TableB's appears to have the candidate key of `{StudyID , SubjectID , VisitCode}`.  Typcially when you have compound candidate key like this you first have a table that looks like `{SurragoteKey, A, B}`  and then a table with the `{SurragoteKey, C}` rather than just `{A,B,C}`That said you're free to make your design how you want, but you will one in to difficulties like the one you described

Comment: I guess I didn't make it clear - I have no control over the design of Table A or Table B, they are pre-existing. That said, I can of course create any temp tables etc. that I want to.

Comment: TableB contains hundreds of values for StudyID, so the solutions using "Where B.StudyID IS NULL" are taking minutes to run and returning hundreds of thousands of extraneous rows. Editing OP to clarify this.

Comment: You'll be fighting perfromance problems like this as long as the DB design is like this. If you think `b.studyid is null` is the issue you can try using `NOT EXISTS ` but I'd be surprised if that helped. You can also as jpw suggested filter to a single study (in this case in the `subjects` cte). If that doesn't work you can try all the perf helpers, like adding indexes, indexed views, triggers that populate tables, applicaiton caching etc. Good luck.

Comment: Don't even get me started on the DB design and data architecture here!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find out the missing visits for subjects, I believe there would be another table for Subject e.g. TableC and would have the relation to study, so joining the TableA and TableC will give the super set of subjects x visits, minus the TableB with this and you get the missing visits for the subjects.

```
SELECT StudyID
     , SubjectID
     , VisitCode
  FROM (SELECT a.StudyID
             , c.SubjectID
             , a.VisitCode
          FROM TableA a 
          LEFT JOIN TableC c ON a.StudyID = c.StudyID
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * 
          FROM TableB)
 WHERE StudyID = 'C1234'
```